# Noetherian spectral space comes from noetherian ring?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a spectral space ([en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_space)), i.e. a space of the form $\textrm{Spec}(A)$ for some commutative ring $A$. If $X$ is noetherian, does there also exist a noetherian ring $B$ such that $X=\textrm{Spec}(B)$?

Comment: $\mathrm{Spec}$ is an (anti-)equivalence from commutative rings to affine scheme, so two rings are isomorphic iff their Spec's are. So, if such a noetherian $B$ exists, your $A$ was already isomorphic to it.

Comment: Oh yes, you're totally right, it's the underlying top space of the Spec not the scheme

Comment: I wonder if Hochster's thesis addresses this?  Off the top of my head, I don't know how to make the following Noetherian topological space $\{p,q,r\}$, with open sets $\{ \{p,q,r\}, \{p,q\}, \{p\} \}$, as the spectrum of a Noetherian ring (it's the spectrum of the non-discrete valuation ring associated to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ with the lex order).

Comment: @KarlSchwede - You may want to take look at my comment below.

Comment: relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/a/330735/141498

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Graph $N_5$ with poset order topology (i.e. poset $M=\{p,q,r\}, P_2=\{p,q\}, P_1=\{p\}, Q=\{r\}, N=\phi$) is not Spec($A$) for Noetherian $A$ because if $a \in Q-P_2$ then 1 = dim$(A/a)$ = dim$(A)-1$ = 2 by the principal ideal theorem.

Comment: See also top of p. 48 in *Ring constructions on spectral spaces* by Christopher Francis Tedd https://www.escholar.manchester.ac.uk/jrul/item/?pid=uk-ac-man-scw:307012 --- link to the PDF file: https://www.escholar.manchester.ac.uk/api/datastream?publicationPid=uk-ac-man-scw:307012&datastreamId=FULL-TEXT.PDF